# UCMA VXML platform support for parsing XML

Tags: xml, lync-2013, ucma, vxml

We are using an instance of UCMA VoiceXMLBrowser in our IVR application. At some point in our flow, we need to fetch some XML content from an external source using a **data** element.

In our web server access log, we can observe that a request will be made to the predefined URI and status code 200 will be returned with the desired XML content. Unfortunately a **error.unsupported.data.name** is thrown which according to the W3C documenation is a sign of our platforms **not supporting parsing XML data into a DOM**.

How can we add this feature to our platform? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The standard is to support XML parsing with DOM EcmaScript classes.
If you cannot do it, it is because that your VoiceXML browser is probably not full compliance with the VoiceXML 2.1.

The method proposed by the standard specification is very complex, and need to add extra DOM classes in your EcmaScript stack. The final syntax to get the XML fields is too heavy.
In our case, we offer another way to use the  tag. We extended the  using with text (enctype=text/plain) and JSON (enctype=application/json). Our Voxiaml VoiceXML interpreter is probably the only one that adds this feature (out of the standard specification). We hope that many other implentations will propose the same option.